# Simulate back button after ajax-submitted form submitted to Preview Form

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, forms, codeigniter

I have a multi-part form where the flow of the data is:

1. Answer the form, SUBMIT (via ajax post)

   - jQuery Form and CodeIgniter validation echoed if present
2. Preview the answers from the form

   - Choices: **Cancel**, **Edit**, **Commit to database**

The three choices are submit buttons with unique names in the preview form.
My **Commit to database** process is finished, while I have difficulty in doing the Cancel and Edit. My current method for the three are (inside the controller):

```
function preview_form_redirect() 
{
  if ( isset($_POST['submit-form']) ) {
    $this->send_to_database();
  } else if ( isset($_POST['edit-form']) ) {
    // return to form with all answers intact
  } else { // CANCEL FORM
    redirect('accounts');
  }
} // END preview_form_redirect()
```

My plan for the Edit option is to **simulate back button** because I'm sure the data and DOM will be intact.

I know my methods for the two are not perfect but I am stuck and do not know what other methods to simulate the two. Are there possible and compatible ways to do the two for my setup?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to do it with Javascript.
You can use this library that uses the html5 push state, or html fragments if your browser does not fully support the HTML5 history API: https://github.com/browserstate/History.js/

When the user clicks on edit button, do something like this:
    History.pushState({state:1}, "State 1", "?state=1");

and register an event on the back button:
    History.Adapter.bind(window,'popstate',function(){ 
        //remove the editable elements from your page
    });

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you. Do you think simulating the browser back button is practical though?

Comment: Yes, I think so. It is now part of the HTML5 specification, and you have a lot of applications that are doing it: Facebook, Gmail, Google Plus, ...

Comment: Thank you very much! My setup of form using AJAX submission + CodeIgniter is pretty complicated and I need all the best practices since I'm just learning :) I really appreciate it!

Comment: Another question: does this refresh the page being loaded (by the back button)? I do not want that particular page to be loaded.

Comment: Nop. It does not cause a page reload. That library takes care of it. Do a simple example with it and then incorporate in your application.

Answer (score 0):

Try with the native js back method: `history.back()`